# sql - update in subquery & same table

Tags: mysql

I want to update multiple lines of data, but an error occurred.

Below is the table information and query statement.

**myTable**

```
ltiNum  ltiCd   updateDate  ClosedOrNot

1   A   2020-07-01  
2   B   2020-07-01  
3   C   2020-07-01  
4   D   2020-07-01  
5   E   2020-07-01  
1   A   2020-08-01  
3   C   2020-08-01  
4   D   2020-08-01  
5   E   2020-08-01  
6   F   2020-08-01
```

**SQL**

```
update myTable 
set closedOrNot = 
        (case when (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM myTable where updateDate Like '2020-08%'
                    and CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) in (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM myTable WHERE updateDate Like '2020-07%'       
        )) then 'existing'
        when (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM myTable where updateDate Like '2020-08%'
                    and CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) not in (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM myTable WHERE updateDate Like '2020-07%'
        )) then 'New'        
         when (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM myTable where updateDate Like '2020-07%'
                    and CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) not in (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM myTable WHERE updateDate Like '2020-08%'
        )) then 'Closed'
    end);
```

**Error code :**

> mysql error code 1093: You can't specify target table for 'myTable'
> update in FROM clause

Where is the problem?

i want see follow images

please help~!

[image]

Comment: I have the impression that  you need to review your case statement. It seem that there is no condition and the CONCAT function is irrelevant. In other words, you-re saying -if a and b then do something regardless of the values of a and b. In regard to CONCAT you=re not joining anything, so you don't need CONCAT at all. Ypu may take advantage of some of the MySQL tutorials available on the net.

Comment: You want me to guess what you are trying to do based on non-working code?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this query? It looks like a bad idea to introduce a new column for something that a query can already tell you. Don't store data redundantly in a database.

Comment: You need to explain the logic that computes the statuses, otherwise it is hard to suggest relevant improvements for the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must encapsule the mytable with in a SELECT

```
update myTable 
set closedOrNot = 
        (case when (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) t1 where updateDate Like '2020-08%'
                    and CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) in (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) t1 WHERE updateDate Like '2020-07%'       
        )) then 'existing'
        when (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) t1 where updateDate Like '2020-08%'
                    and CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) not in (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) t1 WHERE updateDate Like '2020-07%'
        )) then 'New'        
         when (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) t1 where updateDate Like '2020-07%'
                    and CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) not in (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) t1 WHERE updateDate Like '2020-08%'
        )) then 'Closed'
    end);
```

So mysql thinks, that this is another table, but you are basically changing all the rows, because you didn't use a WHERE clause, so that it could happen that further the road, the results could be changed

Basically everything is correct what o told you but your query has another problem

> ```
> CREATE TABLE myTable (
>   `ltiNum` INTEGER,
>   `ltiCd` VARCHAR(1),
>   `updateDate` VARCHAR(10),
>   `closedOrNot` VARCHAR(8)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO myTable
>   (`ltiNum`, `ltiCd`, `updateDate`, `closedOrNot`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'A', '2020-07-01', 'NULL'),
>   ('2', 'B', '2020-07-01', 'Closed'),
>   ('3', '0', '2020-07-01', 'NULL'),
>   ('4', 'D', '2020-07-01', 'NULL'),
>   ('5', 'E', '2020-07-01', 'NULL'),
>   ('1', 'A', '2020-08-01', 'existing'),
>   ('3', '0', '2020-08-01', 'existing'),
>   ('4', 'D', '2020-08-01', 'existing'),
>   ('5', 'E', '2020-08-01', 'existing'),
>   ('6', 'F', '2020-08-01', 'New');
> ```

> ```
> update myTable 
> set closedOrNot = 
>         (case when (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) t1 where updateDate Like '2020-08%'
>                     and CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) in (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) t1 WHERE updateDate Like '2020-07%'       
>         )) then 'existing'
>         when (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) t1 where updateDate Like '2020-08%'
>                     and CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) not in (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) t1 WHERE updateDate Like '2020-07%'
>         )) then 'New'        
>          when (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) t1 where updateDate Like '2020-07%'
>                     and CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) not in (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) t1 WHERE updateDate Like '2020-08%'
>         )) then 'Closed'
>     end);
> ```
>
> ```
> Subquery returns more than 1 row
> ```

> ```
>  SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) 
>  FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) t1 
>  where updateDate Like '2020-08%'
>                     and CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) in (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) t1 WHERE updateDate Like '2020-07%' )
> ```
>
> ```
> | CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) |
> | :------------------- |
> | 1A                   |
> | 30                   |
> | 4D                   |
> | 5E                   |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) t1 where updateDate Like '2020-08%'
>                     and CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) not in (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) t1 WHERE updateDate Like '2020-07%'
>         )
> ```
>
> ```
> | CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) |
> | :------------------- |
> | 6F                   |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) t1 where updateDate Like '2020-07%'
>                     and CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) not in (SELECT CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) t1 WHERE updateDate Like '2020-08%'
>         )
> ```
>
> ```
> | CONCAT(ltiNum,ltiCd) |
> | :------------------- |
> | 2B                   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=440cd20c21de1e865139f915412e61f7)*

As you can see the first CASE retursn 4 results, so that your construction doesn't work-

Comment: I knew what the problem was.
Thanks for the answer for me.!